# Azure API management - multiple URLs?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have deployed multiple apps on azure kubernetes and have azure API management in front.

As I have deployed multiple apps that spans across various portfolios, would it be possible to configure the Azure API management with multiple URLs, ideally per application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can add multiple custom domains to APIM.

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/configure-custom-domain

This feature also depends on the Tier of your APIM. Consumption, Basic and Standard Tier do not have this feature.

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-features